# Angular 6 azure ad roles and audience problem

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory

Hi I have an angular 6 application with separate web API in c# which validates roles for logged on user. For both, Angular and Web API, registrations are separate. Somehow, the audience in JWT web token is coming as Angular app's registration client Id instead of resource URI.
there are 2 questions:
1. Is this valid that we can have 2 different app registrations?
2. If yes, why the audience is not coming correctly. I have checked many forums but not found the solution.
3. The roles are defined in Web API's Manifest file, will they be able to get into JWT token?
Here is the sample for app module of angular 6

[Here is app moduel code sample from angular 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JcVo.png)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is this valid that we can have 2 different app registrations?

Yes that is a valid case. Having a single or multiple app registrations for UI and backend API depends on your setup/scenario. For e.g. one scenario is when API is exposed to be used by not just the Angular frontend, but other applications as well (today or in future) and these other applications have nothing to do with Angular UI application, it would be a good way to setup separate app registrations.

> 2. If yes, why the audience is not coming correctly. I have checked many forums but not found the solution.

This would depend on your code. When requesting Azure AD for token, what is the resource/endpoint you've specified. You haven't included much code as part of your question, so here is a similar example, you may or may not be doing something similar but it should give you some ideas hopefully.

- [Call an Azure AD protected Web API in an AngularJS Single Page App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi)

  Similar setup as yours with separate registrations for API (ToGoAPI) and SPA. Little old as it uses AngularJS but concepts are still same. Specifically, look at the part where endpoints collection is being set in [App.js](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js) (Line 25, where code specifies endpointURL : App ID URI of the To Go API)

> 3. The roles are defined in Web API's Manifest file, will they be able to get into JWT token?

Short answer is yes. As long as you have configured your application manifest correctly and also the user who is signing in (or you're getting the JWT token for) has been assigned one or more roles before hand.

Here are relevant links and a sample application which gives full steps and walk through

- [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles)
- [Authorization in a web app using Azure AD application roles & role claims](http://Authorization%20in%20a%20web%20app%20using%20Azure%20AD%20application%20roles%20&%20role%20claims)

  Assigning application roles to users can be done from Azure Portal.

  [image]

Comment: Thanks Rohit, somehow, it is not working. I am using angular 6. I have edited comments to add snippet from my code. Tried resource, resource id, endpoint. But somehow the audience in JWT token comes as client id of the Angular application registration and not the one of Web API.

Comment: endpoints: {
        'http://localhost:5000/': 'https://xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/b83bb944-90ab-4da6-b476-e2c98a877c96',
        'http://localhost:5000': 'https://xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/b83bb944-90ab-4da6-b476-e2c98a877c96', 
      }, Even this didnt work where I am running API on 5000 port

Comment: ok got it. Is there a particular error you end up getting? Also, I hope you're looking at the JWT token that is being passed to your backend API? I also see that URL is different (http://localhost:4200) and even the guid is different in the image you have with your question.. as compared to your comments.. on a side note,adding code as text to your question instead of image will be better..

Comment: Apologies, it was old screenshot. but the endpoint I am configuring is endpoints: { 'localhost:5000': 'https://xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/b83bb944-90ab-4da6-b476-e2c98a877c96', 'localhost:5000/': 'https://xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/b83bb944-90ab-4da6-b476-e2c98a877c96', }, It is App ID URI of API registration. I think I am not sure what is the syntax of end point URL to configure. Would you be able to comment? it would be great help.

Comment: oh old screenshot threw me off a bit.. no worries.. Here is the way I would try.. see if it makes any difference `var endpoints = {"https://contosotogo.azurewebsites.net/":
            "https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/ToGoAPI",};`